# How to force chop line for ternary operator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, clang-format

How can I force chopping (or keeping manually chopped) ternary operator lines.

```
// clang-formatted
int foobar = bar ? a : b;

// expected
int foobar2 = bar
                ? a
                : b;
```

I started with the `microsoft` style.
These are the applicable (I think) settings in the `.clang-format` file, is there anything I am missing?

```
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true
AlignOperands:   true
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions (other than `// clang-format off` which was already mentioned in a different answer). But neither is very desirable:

1. Set the style option `ColumnLimit: 0`. This will cause clang-format to preserve the multi-line format if it is already multi-line. But if the ternary operator is all on one line, it won't break it into multiple lines. This can also be achieved by using the pre-defined `WebKit` style, which internally sets `ColumnLimit: 0`.

   The [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) says:

   > A column limit of 0 means that there is no column limit. In this case, clang-format will respect the input’s line breaking decisions within statements unless they contradict other rules.

   Of course, this has the disadvantage of disabling the usual column limit of 80 characters in all of your code.
2. Put a comment after the `bar` but before the `?`, like this:

   ```
    int foobar2 = bar //
                      ? a
                      : b;
   ```

   The comment prevents clang-format from combining it back into one line. But the disadvantage is you have to manually add that comment to every ternary operator, and it looks a little ugly.

Answer (score 0):

What about partially turn off the *clang-format*? Like:

```cpp
// clang-format off

int foobar2 = bar
                ? a
                : b;

// clang-format on
```

Comment: While this does technically answer the question, it feels a bit like a cheat ;) After all, the OP is asking how to get the tool to do something specific, and saying not to use the tool at all, seems not so useful.

Comment: while that technically does work, I would prefer to not have to do that. the hope was to automagically format everything.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the "keeping manually chopped" part of the question :)